# actualizar una datatable en tiempo real laravel

Tags: laravel, script

helpme
 
  
    
      Nombre

```
   <th scope="col">Nombre proyecto</th>
 <th scope="col">Aprobado </th>
  <th scope="col">No Aprobado</th>
   <th scope="col">Abstencion</th>
</tr>
```

```
@foreach ($mostrarusers as $mostraruser)
<tr>


  <td>{{$mostraruser->usuario}}</td>

    <td>{{$mostraruser->proyecto}}</td>
    <td>{{$mostraruser->si}}</td>
    <td>{{$mostraruser->no}}</td>
     <td>{{$mostraruser->voto_en_blanco}}</td>

</tr>
  @endforeach
```

la idea es que se muestre entiempo real la tabla

la funcion del controller es esta

```
$mostrarusers = DB::table('votos')
->join('users','users.id','=','votos.user_id')

->join('nombre_votos','nombre_votos.id','=','votos.id_nombre_votos')
->select('users.name as usuario', 'nombre_votos.nombre as 
proyecto','si','no','voto_en_blanco')
->whereDate('votos.created_at', Carbon::today())

->get();
```

Comment: no tiene que ver Laravel, eso en todo caso es tema de que muestres lo que llevas hecho

Comment: ps lo intento hacer un un script simple y no me  actualiza

Comment: Lo que te intenta decir mi compañero es que no tiene nada que ver con Laravel, estás usando JQUERY para "refrescar" el contenido de un div.

Si lo que quieres es refrescar el contenido del div con algún dato del Servidor(php hecho con laravel), necesitarás usar ajax, ya que estás confundiendo cliente-servidor por ese .load(/ALGO) que te veo en el código.

Comment: que base de datos estas usando?

Comment: MySQL, a mi me muestra los datos y todo funciona bien pero lo quiero hacer que se actualice el div en tiempo real. tengo esta demo de como se ve https://chatmeme.000webhostapp.com/pantalla

Comment: lo quieres hacer en ajax

Answer (score 1):

Corrígeme si me equivoco (ya que no enviaste muchos datos para entenderte mejor), pero yo supongo que tu tienes algo así en tu controlador:

```
function controladorVista()
{
 $mostrarusers = DB::table('votos')
  ->join('users','users.id','=','votos.user_id')
  ->join('nombre_votos','nombre_votos.id','=','votos.id_nombre_votos')
  ->select('users.name as usuario', 'nombre_votos.nombre as 
   proyecto','si','no','voto_en_blanco')
  ->whereDate('votos.created_at', Carbon::today())
  ->get()
  return view('index', compact('mostrarusers'));
}
```

Si es así, lamento decirte que tu lista solo se actualizará cuando hagas refresh(recargues la página). Ahora partiendo de eso las opciones que tienes para actualizar tu página sin necesidad de recargar esta serian:

1 - Hacer una petición vía ajax a una ruta/endpoint de tu servidor en laravel, esto te traerá tu lista y podrás actualizar tu tabla, para ello tendrías que adicionarle la función setInterval de js que la ejecute cada cierto tiempo (tal vez cada 3 minutos).

**En tu controller:**

```
function getMostrarUsers()
    {
        $mostrarusers = DB::table('votos')
          ->join('users','users.id','=','votos.user_id')
          ->join('nombre_votos','nombre_votos.id','=','votos.id_nombre_votos')
          ->select('users.name as usuario', 'nombre_votos.nombre as 
           proyecto','si','no','voto_en_blanco')
          ->whereDate('votos.created_at', Carbon::today())
          ->get();
        return response()->json($mostrarusers, 200);
    }
```

**En tu archivo de rutas(routes/web.php) por defecto**

```
Route::get('/mostrar-users', 'TuControlador@getMostrarUsers')->name('rest.getMostrarUsers');
```

**(En tu view/vista)** Entonces en el parte de tus `<scripts>` o un archivo `js` externo, sería más o menos así (Usando `JQuery`):

```
function cargarTabla(){
        $.ajax({
            url     : '{{ route('rest.getMostrarUsers')}}',
            method  : 'GET',
            success : function(r){
                let lista = r;
                let htmlCode = ``;
                $.each(lista, function(index, item){
                    htmlCode+=`<tr>
                                <td>${item.nombreProyecto}</td>
                                <td>${totalDeSi}</td>
                                <td>${totalDeNo}</td>
                                <td>${totalVotoBlanco}</td>
                            </tr>`;
                });
                $('#id-mi-tabla tbody').html(htmlCode);
            }
        });
    }
```

**En el mismo documento usando el document ready, cargarías esta función cada cierto tiempo así:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        setInterval(cargarTabla, 180000);//Cada 3 minutos (180 mil milisegundos)
    });
```

2 - Usar websockets, que sería lo óptimo, con esto podrías configurar que cada vez que haces un insert/update/delete de algo relacionado a tu lista(como un voto), disparé un evento en laravel que se encargue de actualizar tu tabla a todos los clientes que estén suscritos a este. esto si sería en tiempo real.

Comment: me podrias mostrar algun video donde se maneje el websocket en laravel para ir aprendiendo a usarlo

Comment: solo me muestra el json no las tablas como puedo mostrarlo en el view